# Removing part of an image from the 3d plot

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image: img1]

In the above image, blue circle at the center and rectangle at the bottom represent defects while light blue area represents normal area.

[image: img2]

When I use slice function for 3d representation, how do I get rid of light blue area so that we only see circle and rectangle in 3d plot?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you take a slice of a 3D image, you obtain a 2D image. So your question seems not to be related to 3D. Please try to be to the point, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

[image]

Here is the code I came up with (note that it depends on a threshold value that you have to compute youself, from your whole dataset, this is why it is a little noisy):

```
clear all;
close all;

pkg load image

im=double(rgb2gray(imread("5JpXg.jpg")));
im=im(10:end-10,10:end-10);

%you can try to find a better threshold based on your data
threshold=100;
im(im<threshold)=0;%or im(im>threshold)=0 if you want everything to be blank except the circle and the rectangle

[m n]=size(im);

num_non_zero_pixels=size(im(im~=0),1);
x=zeros(3,num_non_zero_pixels);

counter=1;
for i=1:m
  for j=1:n
    if(0~=im(i,j))
      x(1,counter)=i;
      x(2,counter)=j;
      x(3,counter)=im(i,j);
      counter=counter+1;
    end
  end
end

plot3(x(1,:)',x(2,:)',x(3,:)',"*");
```

Comment: Well.. I meant more like: I want everything blank except circle and rectangular part.. that would also be a matter of setting the threshold?
but yes your answer definitely helps

Comment: Well, then you just have to change the "<" to ">" in the threshold line :) try this: 
  im(im>threshold)=0;

Comment: I added a comment to the corresponding line, I hope this does what you want! Btw, for your future posts, please include more details (at least a bit of code, your own efforts etc). I personally don't mind, but many users will downvote and tell you that SO is not a code providing service, and so on. Also, use nicer formatting!